# Wortstellung der Objekte/des Subjekts in Nebensätzen (O-S-V möglich?)

Tags: word-order, conjunction, subordinate-clause, subject, objects

Ich verzweifle gerade an der Wortstellung in Nebensätzen bzw. an Abweichungen der Standardregel
und habe auch schon viel recherchiert, aber es scheint, dass niemand diese Frage thematisieren will.
Ich bin unendlich dankbar für Hilfe!

Zur Frage: Wann darf/kann das Objekt vor dem Subjekt stehen in einem Nebensatz?

Beispiel: Eine Studie hat ergeben, dass die Auswahl den Studenten schwerfällt. /
......, dass den Studenten die Auswahl schwerfällt.

Sind beide Sätze in Standarddeutsch grammatikalisch korrekt?
Wo ist in diesem Satz das Subjekt/der Nominativ?
Welche Abweichungen gibt es zu der Regel S-O-V in Nebensätzen?

Meine Ideen:
Ich weiß, dass in der gesprochenen Sprache und allgemein im Deutschen die Wortstellung recht frei ist - außer die des Verbs und im Hauptsatz ja auch das Subjekt an unterschiedlichen Stellen stehen kann und je nach Betonung/Hervorhebung eines Teils dieser an erste Stelle rücken kann.

Bei Nebensätzen, Satzgefügen erscheint mir das aber nicht so einfach?
Ich weiß auch, dass es Subjekt/Objektsätze gibt und dann ein ganzer Satzteil das Subjekt ist, aber bei meinem obigen Beispiel erscheint mir das nicht der Fall zu sein.

Ich habe irgendwo auch gelesen, dass das Subjekt nur als Pronomen immer direkt nach der Konjunktionen kommen muss? Ansonsten aber, wenn Dativ und Akkusativ und Nominativ als Nomen ausgeschrieben sind und die Bedeutung des Satzes nicht verändert wird, sie recht frei getauscht werden können. Aber warum lernen Deutschschüler dann meist nur diese Wortstellung: Subjekt vor Objekt?

---

(Update)

- In meinem obigen Beispiel ist die Veränderung der Reihenfolge problemlos möglich,
  in anderen Fällen jedoch nicht und mir scheint besonders dann nicht,
  wenn das Subjekt als Pronomen steht, also dass es dann vor dem Objekt kommen muss,
  oder nicht? Gibt es sonstige Fälle, wo es eben nicht möglich ist?
- Gibt es also keinerlei Regel, sondern verlangt das Sprachgefühl eines Muttersprachlers?
- Wie erklärt man solche Fälle einem Nichtmuttersprachler?
- Wie kann ich "die Auswahl" in meinem Beispiel sicher als "Subjekt/Nominativ" erkennen,
  könnte es nicht auch Akkusativ sein?
- Ist der ganze Satz ein Objektsatz (Akkusativ)?
- Und gibt es einen Unterschied, wenn ich folgenden Satz habe:
  "Einige große Universitäten bieten so viele Studiengänge an,
  dass den Studenten die Auswahl schwer fällt"

  - Gibt es hier also 2 Subjekte, ein Akkusativobjekt und ein Dativobjekt?

Comment: "... die Wortstellung recht frei ist - außer die des Verbes ..." - so ist es. Beide Beispielsätze sind richtig. *Die Auswahl* ist das Subjekt.

Comment: Ich habe die Fortschreibung der Fragen aus der Pseudo-Antwort hierher verschoben. Das Problem, dass mehrfache Fragen schwierig zu beantworten sind, ist damit aber nicht gelöst. Ich würde empfehlen, separate Fragen zu erstellen mit einem Verweis auf diese hier, wo das angebracht ist.

Comment: Es gibt einige Regeln für die Wortstellung, die über die Position des Verbs hinausgehen, wie Pronomen vor Nomen, Dativ vor Akkusativ, außer bei Pronomen, bestimmt vor unbestimmt. Das sind aber eher "weiche" Regeln, von denen abgewichen werden kann, wenn ein Satzteil hervorgehoben werden soll.

Comment: Ich habe versucht, die nachgelieferten Zusatzfragen in meiner Antwort zu berücksichtigen.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, es stimmt, dass die Wortstellung im Deutschen sehr frei ist.

Sie ist aber *nicht beliebig*. Sind die Grundregeln "Verbzweitstellung im Hauptsatz, Verbletztstellung im Nebensatz" eingehalten, haben Abweichungen von der "Lehrbuch-Standard-Wortstellung" meistens einen Grund und tragen für einen Nichtmuttersprachler (manchmal auch für den Muttersprachler, der nicht so genau hinhört) oftmals so subtile Bedeutungs- und Betonungsunterschiede, dass man ihnen wohl lieber die "normale" unbetonte Form beibringt, um sie nicht unnötig mit fragenden Blicken und hochgezogenen Augenbrauen des Gegenübers zu konfrontieren. Es wird also im Allgemeinen die neutrale, "normale", unbetonte Version gelehrt.

(Der Deutsch C2-Level ist nicht umsonst mit "Kann sich spontan, sehr flüssig und genau ausdrücken und auch bei komplexeren Sachverhalten *feinere Bedeutungsnuancen deutlich* machen." markiert)

Zu deinen Fragen:

Das Subjekt darf in einem Nebensatz *immer* vor oder nach dem Objekt stehen. Zwingend ist nur, dass das Verb am Ende steht. Deine Beispiele sind also grammatikalisch beide richtig. Es gibt aber einen feinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Versionen:

Steht das Subjekt vorne (in deinem Beispiel "die Auswahl"), wird eben dies betont, dasselbe gilt auch für das Objekt. Am besten läßt sich das mit einem zugesetzten "Aber"-Satz verstehen:

> Eine Studie hat ergeben, dass die Auswahl den Studenten schwer fällt - die Durchführung aber nicht.

> Eine Studie hat ergeben, dass den Studenten die Auswahl schwer fällt - den Professoren aber nicht.

(Hier ist der Unterschied zugegebenermaßen so klein, dass er auch einem Muttersprachler oft nicht auffält).

Ähnlich gelagert ist die sog. "TeKaMoLo"-Reihenfolge bei adverbialen Bestimmungen - Ich kenne keine für Muttersprachler gedachte deutsche Grammatik, wo das als Regel drinstehen würde - Aber in jedem "Deutsch als Fremdsprache"-Buch wird sie gelehrt.

Deine nachgereichten Zusatzfragen:

1. In den allermeisten Fällen ist der Tausch von Subjekt und Objekt möglich - auch, wenn das Subjekt ein Pronomen ist (das mag dann auch ein bißchen ungewöhnlicher klingen, ist aber trotzdem "richtig")

   > Die Auswahl ist so schwierig, dass diese den Studenten schwerfällt.

   > Die Auswahl ist so schwierig, dass den Studenten diese schwerfällt.

   [grammatikalisch korrekt, hört sich aber auch für Muttersprachler ungewöhnlich (möglicherweise "formell") an].
2. Es gibt eine *Norm*, aber keine Regel für die Position von Subjekt und Objekt im Nebensatz (solange man die Regel "Verbletztstellung im Nebensatz" nicht verletzt).
3. Ich denke, die praktizierte Methode beim Lehren ist, einen Unterschied zwischen passivem und aktiven Sprachgebrauch zu machen - "Ihr solltet eure eigenen Sätze nach der Norm bilden, euch aber nicht verwirren lassen, wenn ihr von der Norm abweichenden Satzbau hört" - Ob man Sätze, z.B. in Klausuren, als Fehler werten sollte, wenn sie zwar der Regel, aber nicht der Norm entsprechen? Falsch sind sie ja nicht...
4. "Die Auswahl" kann man nach dem Ausschlußprinzip als Nominativ erkennen - Der Nebensatz braucht ein Subjekt, und "Auswahl" ist das einzige Nomen, das im Nominativ stehen könnte ("den Studenten" kann es ja nicht sein).
5. "Dass" kann (u.A.) Subjekt- Objekt- und Attributsätze einleiten. Eine "Streichprobe" hilft hier: "Eine Studie hat ergeben" kann nicht alleine stehen - hier fehlt eindeutig ein Objekt, das dem Satz überhaupt einen Sinn gibt - das könnte "ein Ergebnis" oder aber ", dass die Studenten Schwierigkeiten haben" sein - Ja, hier handelt es sich eindeutig um einen Objektsatz. Und ja, auch wenn der Objektsatz natürlich nicht in einem bestimmten Fall (hier Akkusativ) steht, würden wir mit dem Akkusativ nach ihm fragen - Der Objektsatz ersetzt hier ein Objekt im Akkusativ.
6. Deine letzte Frage verstehe ich nur teilweise: Das neue Beispiel ist kein Objektsatz mehr, sondern ein Adverbialsatz - der Nebensatz ersetzt kein Objekt des Hauptsatzes mehr. "Studiengänge" ist das Akkusativobjekt des Hauptsatzes, "den Studenten" das Dativobjekt des Nebensatzes - andere Objekte gibt es hier nicht.